# Testing future methods: data scope

Tags: unit-test, dml, future

I'm trying to test my @future method, in which I'm performing Custom Object update, but when I'm asserting values, updated object field equals null. Could it be a problem with method scope? I'm adding objects in @testSetup method and then updating a field in future method, but I don't see updated record fields in test method.

```
public static List<Custom_Object__c> objects;

@testSetup static void setup() {
    objects = new List<Custom_Object__c>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < objectAmount; ++i) {
        objects.add(new Custom_Object__c(Hosting_Url__c = 'http://google.com'));
    }
    insert objects;
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest static void testOk() {
    setup();
    Test.startTest();

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new UrlStatusHttpMock());
    UrlCheck.checkAndUpdate(JSON.serialize(objects));
    Test.stopTest();        

    for (Integer i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        System.assertEquals('Living', objects.get(i).Url_Status__c, 'Wrong Url Status');
    }
}
```

And tested method:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void checkAndUpdate(String objects) {
    List<Custom_Object__c> objectsToUpdate = new List<Custom_Object__c>();
    List<Custom_Object__c> objects = (List<Custom_Object__c>)JSON.deserialize(objects, List<Custom_Object__c>.class);

    for (Custom_Object__c object : objects) {            
            //some operations...
            object.Url_Status__c = 'Living';   
            objectsToUpdate.add(object);
        }
    }
    update objectsToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-query for the records to find their status in the database.

```
List<MyObject__c> updatedRecords = [SELECT MyField__c FROM MyObject__c];
system.assertEquals(initialCount, updatedRecords.size(), 'All records should remain in the database');
for (MyObject__c record : updatedRecords)
{
    // these records should be affected by your action
}
```